# MySQL select multiple rows from two tables, group by row from one table

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two tables:

1)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    class__id INT,
    book_order INT,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    content TEXT(65535)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

2)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book_image(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    class__id INT,
    type VARCHAR(12),
    type__id INT,
    image_order INT,
    url VARCHAR(50)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

I need to get a list of books for a given `book.class__id`, and all images for each of those books with `book_image.type = 'book'` and `book_image.type__id = book.id`. Furthermore, the book_images need to be ordered by the `image_order` column, separately for each book.

I need the resulting object to look somewhat like this:

```
object(stdClass)
'books' => array (size=2)
    0 => 
        object(stdClass)
        'id' => 13
        'class__id' => 55
        'book_order' => 1
        'title' => xyz
        'content' => xyz
        'book_images' => array (size=2)
            0 =>
                object(stdClass)
                'id' => 529
                'class__id' => 55
                'type' => book
                'type__id' => 13
                'image_order' => 1
                'url' => xyz
            1 =>
                object(stdClass)
                'id' => 27
                'class__id' => 55
                'type' => book
                'type__id' => 13
                'image_order' => 2
                'url' => xyz
    1 => 
        object(stdClass)
        'id' => 21
        'class__id' => 55
        'book_order' => 2
        'title' => xyz
        'content' => xyz
        'book_images' => array (size=1)
            0 =>
                object(stdClass)
                'id' => 420
                'class__id' => 55
                'type' => book
                'type__id' => 21
                'image_order' => 1
                'url' => xyz
```

I'd like to avoid a convoluted foreach() loop with mutliple queries one after the other for each book... I tried various types of joins and select subqueries to no avail.

How do I do this with a single query?

Comment: Your output is not what I would expect from a SQL query... are you using a front end? (this is the kind of thing for which a NoSQL DBMS, such as MongoDB, might be a better choice)

Comment: That is not actual output... only what I am trying to achieve :) Sorry if that was confusing.